# Retrieve data from onbindviewholder using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working with firebase in android. The problem I facing is data stored on my database but I can't show them. Here is my code :

```
 final FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
                    .setQuery(databaseReference, Blog.class)
                    .build();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>

            firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_row, parent, false);
            return new BlogViewHolder(view);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, Blog model) {

            holder.setDesc(model.getDescription());
            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            Log.w("ok","ok");
        }
```

How can i show them in my view.

Comment: Why you are not able to show data?..have you fetched that data before adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this...

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```